# Large-scale volume rendering and visualization libraries for terabyte-size data

Tags: bigdata, visualization, data-visualization, volume-rendering, raymarching

I want to visualise 3D volumes of data that span between a few gigabytes to a few terabytes. One solution would be to roll my own but this may take some time. To avoid this I am currently exploring what are current available solutions. The more I look into it, the more software I find. Some examples include `ParaView/VTK`, `OSPRay`, `Embree`, `Splotch`, `NVIDIA GVDB/OptiX`, etc.

Some of this software provide complete solutions for visualization, and data manipulation (e.g., `ParaView/VTK`). Others are focused mostly on high performance rendering (e.g., `Embree`). Others provide low-level APIs for rendering (e.g., `GVDB/OptiX`). Some are optimised for particular hardware (e.g., `Embree` for Intel hardware, `GVDB/Optix` for NVIDIA GPUs). Others include infrastructure for distributed rendering (e.g., `ParaView/VTK`) which allows them to claim that they can render multi-terabyte-sized data sets, while others leave this functionality to the user. Arguably, multi-terabyte-sized data set volume rendering could also be performed on a single machine using some clever LOD and out-of-core algorithms, but let's leave this for another discussion. Finally, there are also a gazillion software that come out from university research projects and academia that are built to solve particular problems and are no longer maintained.

I wonder if anybody here has experience with such software and can give me some pointers or advice on which software/libraries are worth experimenting with. My ideal requirements are the following:

- Perform volume rendering/ray marching on data sets up to a few terabytes in interactive frame rates (let's say > 10 FPS).
- Take advantage of different parallel architectures (CPU, GPU, multiple nodes)
- Implement/support level-of-detail algorithms.
- Be able to add widgets in the rendered scene. E.g., axes arrows, clipping planes, etc.
- Be in the form of a library that provides a public API to use. Ideally in Python, but I guess making a Python wrapper around a C/C++ API myself is quite feasible.
- They are actively maintained and have proper documentation.

I am not necessarily looking for a software library that includes all the above, but, the more the merrier! :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AstrOne,

Ingo here, from the OSPRay team ;-)

"Terabytes" sounds interesting .... Would be happy to have a look at the kind of data you'd like to be rendering w/ OSPRay ... send me an email!

Comment: Welcome on SO Ingo, putting aside the discussion about making publicly available your email address here, what you ask is typically the sort of thing to be put in comments.